# How to Get FHIR Photo for Patient from a URL

Tags: hl7-fhir

Consider the FHIR Patient data at http://spark.furore.com/fhir/Patient/f201.

How can I get the photo object referenced therein at URL "binary/@f006"??

I would have thought an HTTP GET on http://spark.furore.com/fhir/binary/@f006 would have done it, but alas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data there is wrong. Your conversion to the get was correct, but you ended up with a wrong URL because the reference is wrong in the first place.

It should say: url="Binary/f006" which would equate to a get of http://spark.furore.com/fhir/Binary/f006. That doesn't work either, which is another error in the way things are defined.

See http://gforge.hl7.org/gf/project/fhir/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=6107 for follow ups

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this reference is outdated, and we are not distributing Binaries currently as part of the examples in the FHIR specification. Our server Spark loads the examples from the specification when we initialize the database, hence the images are not there.

For now, I have uploaded the correct image to Binary/f006 and have updated the link in Patient/f201, so things should work now. When we re-initialize the database (we don't do this often), these changes will be reversed, but a simple PUT to Binary/f006 and an update of Patient/f201 will fix this of course.

Comment: Thanks Ewout. Question, though: At http://spark.furore.com/fhir/Patient, patient f201 seems to be absent from the feed now. Any chance of restoring this fellow with the photo linked?

Comment: Hi Marc, there are 374 or so Patients, so f201 is not on the first page of search results. If you are using the .NET client, just call client.Continue() to get to the next page or results (or try something equivalent in java or any api).

Alternatively, specify a more specific search: like http://spark.furore.com/fhir/Patient?name=roel and you will find patient f201